# Should i always use external style sheet even if the style is for one particular page

Tags: css

Since External Style Sheet will be kept in cache, so it will be faster for page load with frequenly visit.Should i always using external style sheet instead of embedded style sheet even if a style is used only for one particular page. The only drawback i can think of is if we use only external style sheet we might have a lot of file in folders styles and this can be messy and confused for others fellow developer compared with using embedded style sheet for css that use only on that page.

Comment: For standalone pages, I'll sometimes use a `style` tag on the page if I know the styles will only ever be used on that page. It avoids polluting global styles and potentially saves an HTTP request if another stylesheet isn't needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's for one page, and only that page, then no.  You'll induce an unnecessary GET request on your server to grab that CSS file.

**Edit**:  To answer the question in your comment "Will using an external CSS document have an overhead of a GET request?" the answer is yes.  For each file not included in the HTML document you're accessing (i.e. external javascript files, images, external stylesheets, etc) the client's browser will have to make another GET request to attain those files.

An embedded CSS is included in the first GET response for that page (it *is* part of the HTML response, after all).

In external style-sheet case scenario, you'd be imposing two GET requests (one for the HTML document, **and another for the CSS file**) as opposed to the single GET request to just embed the CSS into your document.

See the wiki on HTTP for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message

Comment: So using external CSS will have an overhead for get request ? i don't know about that. How is it different from embedded css ? don't we have to use get request too ?

Comment: That's just one request for the HTML page. Having an external stylesheet means one request for HTML, and one for CSS, which makes two.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP requests are costly as far as speed goes.  I'd try to minimize them.  For organization sake, try to keep things in external stylesheets, but if it's just a couple of things applicable to only that page, it makes sense to use an embedded stylesheet.  You have to find the right balance of the two.